# Get Access token throwing an error "The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'"

Tags: rest, sharepoint, postman, access-token, sharepoint-online

I trying to get the SharePoint Online Access token in PostMan. so that I can use in Power Apps custom connector. It's throwing an error. I have tried with both GET and POST menthod
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFAsZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The value of `grant_type` should be `client_credentials`.

From your sceenshot, you are using hyphen `-` instead of underscore `_`.

Comment: I have changed grant_type as you suggested, but still the same error.

Comment: Well. From the error, looks like parameter grant_type is missed in the body. Please make sure that you enter it correctly

Comment: Try making the HTTP type from `GET` to `POST`